# Знак препинания в СПП цели

Tags: пунктуация

*Но никто на свете и не ускользал так, как этот, потому что в своей любви он всегда шел не дальше определенного предела: чтобы ничто не помешало ему сохранить себя свободным для нее.*

Скажите, пожалуйста, по Вашему мнению как носителей языка использование двоеточия перед **чтобы** оправдано? 
Спрашиваю, потому что в оригинале стоит двоеточие и меня интересует, копировал ли переводчик знак препинания или это вполне корректно по правилам русского языка?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

После "предел" идет пояснение, можно вставить "а именно", двоеточие вполне оправдано.